# FakerLibrary: Adding a custom provider fails

Tags: python, robotframework

When I run the following code, I'm facing some difficulty. Calling the [Robot Framework FakerLibrary](https://github.com/guykisel/robotframework-faker) `Add Provider` keyword requires two arguments, instead of the expected 1: name of the module. This seems to me to be correct.

As the Robot Framework Library is a [Dynamic Hybrid library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#hybrid-library-api), the actual keywords come from the [Faker Python module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Faker). In the [Generator class](https://github.com/joke2k/faker/blob/master/faker/generator.py) the actual `Add Provider` method can be found. However, it only takes 2 arguments; one being self: `def add_provider(self, provider)`. So, it should only require 1 argument when called from Robot.

Using the normal Faker keywords works as expected and I'm not having any issues. I'm suspecting that the import through the Dynamic Library doesn't support the Faker module setup as I'm seeing a few Keywords in the [Keyword Documentation](https://guykisel.github.io/robotframework-faker/) that require self as an input argument.

For now I've resorted in creating a wrapper around Faker for custom keywords but like the generic approach better. So that is why I would like to solve this issue.

The Robot Script for this example.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    FakerLibrary    
*** Test Cases ***
Faker Custom Provider Generate Data

    ${fakerLib}    Get Library Instance    FakerLibrary
    Add Provider    ${fakerLib}    OceanProvider
```

The custom provider Python code. When using it with regular Python programming this works as expected but not when adding it through Robot Keywords:

```
from faker.providers import BaseProvider

class OceanProvider(BaseProvider):

    __provider__ = "ocean"
    __lang__     = "en_US"

    oceans = [
        u'Atlantic', u'Pacific', u'Indian', u'Arctic', u'Southern',
    ]

    @classmethod
    def ocean(cls):
        return cls.random_element(cls.oceans)
```

Comment: You have to remember that arguments passed in from robot are strings. `add_provider` almost certainly requires an actual class passed to it.

Comment: `self` is indeed a reference to the instantiated class, but as with all other keyword libraries the self reference is not needed to be provided from Robot Script itself. In the [Generator](https://github.com/guykisel/robotframework-faker/blob/master/robotframework-faker/FakerLibrary/keywords.py) class the `__getattr__` method is triggered. If I change `faker.generator.Generator.__dict__[name]` for `getattr(self._fake, name)` I do get past that point but when I then call the method (`FakerLibrary.ocean`)  it says that this keyword is not present in the library.